# Plotting a function on a triangular domain using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to draw a function on a triangular domain using tikz.
For example, I would like to draw the function x*y on (-1, -1) -- (-1, 1) -- (1, -1).

This is a MWE for the rectangular domain (-1, 1) x (-1, 1).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,small,view={120}{40}]
\addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1] {x*y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I draw this function only on a triangular part of the domain?

Cheers

---

Thank you for your replies.

One follow-up question: I noticed that when clipping several functions using addplot3, depending on the view, the plots often disappear. Consider e.g.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,small,view={-45}{10},zmin=-1,zmax=1]
\clip (axis cs:-1,-1) -- (axis cs:1,1) -- (axis cs:-1,1) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1,color=gray,faceted color=black,opacity=0.05] {x*y};
\addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1,color=red,faceted color=red,opacity=0.05] {(2*x*x+2*x+2*y*y-2*y)/(2*x-2*y+4)};
\addplot3[patch,patch type=triangle,color=blue,faceted color=blue,fill opacity=0.2] coordinates {(-1,-1,1) (1,1,1) (-1,1,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I change

```
view={-45}{10}
```

to

```
view={0}{90}
```

you can see the plots. However, with the aforementioned view, you cannot. Why is that?

Cheers

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Comment: Like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/6gETo.png. by clipping.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I'm looking for. Could you provide an easy example of how to use clipping?

Comment: It is easy. See the answer below. BTW if you add `@<username>` (as in `@HarishKumar`) that user will be notified about the comment.

Comment: Fabian, it's better that you start new questions, making mention of previous ones if necessary, for follow up questions. They will receive more atention.

Comment: Thank you @Ignasi. I have posted the question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213389/clipping-3d-plots-using-tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to plot the curve and clip it by

```
\clip  (-1, -1) -- (-1, 1) -- (1, -1) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,y domain=-1:1] {x*y};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,small,view={120}{40}]
\clip  (-1, -1) -- (-1, 1) -- (1, -1) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,y domain=-1:1] {x*y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```