# Clipping 3D plots using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

This is a follow-up question to [Plotting a function on a triangular domain using pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213089/plotting-a-function-on-a-triangular-domain-using-tikz).

I am interested in plotting three functions on a triangular domain, specifically

1. x*y
2. (2*x*x+2*x+2*y*y-2*y)/(2*x-2*y+4)
3. x-y+1

on the triangle (-1, -1) -- (-1, 1) -- (1, -1).

Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,small,view={-45}{10},zmin=-1,zmax=1]
\clip (axis cs:-1,-1) -- (axis cs:-1,1) -- (axis cs:1,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,color=gray,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1,faceted color=black,opacity=0.05] {x*y};
\addplot3[surf,color=red,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1,faceted color=red,opacity=0.05] {(2*x*x+2*x+2*y*y-2*y)/(2*x-2*y+4)};
\addplot3[surf,color=blue,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1,faceted color=blue,opacity=0.05] {x-y+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, you cannot see anything :) If I change

```
view={-45}{10}
```

to

```
view={0}{90}
```

you can see the plots. However, with the aforementioned view, you cannot. Why is that?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key `clip` is a two-dimensional construct which is applied after the 3d projection. It is only applicable to 3d clipping for special cases.

What you want is a parameterized triangle. To this end, you have to find a map

```
X=X(s,t)
Y=Y(s,t)
```

for `0<= s <=1` and `0<= t <= 1` such that `(X,Y)` represents your desired triangle.

Let us focus on the simple case: the unit triangle with vertices `(0,0)`,  `(1,0)` and `(0,1)`. A possibility to define `X(s,t)` and `Y(s,t)` is to use

```
X(s,t) = s
Y(s,t) = t* (1-s)
```

This nonlinear equation ensures that we can sample a matrix of values `t`, `s` and scale them such that they fit into the triangle. Naturally, one of the corners will receive lots of data points in this approach (feel free to experiment with a parametric plot with `domain=0:1` and these values for X and Y).

In order to map this approach to your triangle, we can simply use a simple linear map as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    view={-45}{10},
    zmin=-1,zmax=1,
    variable=s,
    variable y=t,
    domain=0:1,
]
\def\triangleParamX{-1+ 2*s}
\def\triangleParamY{-1+ 2*(1-s)*t}
\addplot3[surf,color=gray,faceted color=black,opacity=0.05] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,x*y);
\addplot3[surf,color=red,faceted color=red,opacity=0.05] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{(2*x*x+2*x+2*y*y-2*y)/(2*x-2*y+4)});
\addplot3[surf,color=blue,faceted color=blue,opacity=0.05] (\triangleParamX,\triangleParamY,{x-y+1});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the image with `view={0}{90}`:

[image]

Note that a parametric plot requires `X(s,t)`, `Y(s,t)`, and `Z(s,t)`. In my solution, `Z` depends *implicitly* on `s` and `t`: it depends on `x` and `y`. This is a special feature of `pgfplots`: it defines the math variables `x` and `y` to the final numbers `X(s,t)` and `Y(s,t)`, respectively. Consequently, we can define `Z` in terms of `x` and `y` (since pgfplots evaluates `X` and `Y` before `Z`). This is also the reason why I defined `variable=s` and `variable y=t`, otherwise the sampling variable and the resulting `X` and `Y` would overwrite each other.

Comment: Thank you @Christian for your detailed answer. I wasn't aware that clip is primarily for 2d clipping. This is now an elegant solution to my problem. Also, thank you for pgfplots; it's an excellent package!