# pgfplots: Conditional plotting of a 3D surface

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Considering the following data

```
3.1 1   21.8
3.1 0.98    19.16666667
3.1 0.96    17.83333333
3.1 0.94    16.16666667
3.1 0.92    15.5
3.1 0.9 14.83333333
3.1 0.88    14.16666667
3.1 0.86    13.5
3.1 0.84    12.83333333
3.1 0.82    12.16666667
3.1 0.8 12.16666667
3.1 0.78    11.5
3.1 0.76    100
3.1 0.74    100

3.3 1   21.83333333
3.3 0.98    20.5
3.3 0.96    18.5
3.3 0.94    16.83333333
3.3 0.92    15.5
3.3 0.9 14.83333333
3.3 0.88    14.16666667
3.3 0.86    13.5
3.3 0.84    12.83333333
3.3 0.82    12.16666667
3.3 0.8 12.16666667
3.3 0.78    11.5
3.3 0.76    11.5
3.3 0.74    11.5

3.5 1   21.83333333
3.5 0.98    20.5
3.5 0.96    18.5
3.5 0.94    17.16666667
3.5 0.92    15.5
3.5 0.9 14.83333333
3.5 0.88    14.16666667
3.5 0.86    13.5
3.5 0.84    12.83333333
3.5 0.82    12.16666667
3.5 0.8 12.16666667
3.5 0.78    11.5
3.5 0.76    11.5
3.5 0.74    11.5
```

where the first column is `x` values, the second column is `y` values and the third column is `z` values.

How is it possible to plot a 3D surface while making a condition for hiding/removing the surface regions of `z` values equal to 100?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407905/134574), see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Phelype](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410990/p#comment1026025_410990) already linked in the comment below the question, key is to add the option `unbounded coords=jump`. Then the only thing remaining is to transfer the `100` to `NaN`. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%        view={0}{90},
        % you need to add this to get the desired result
        unbounded coords=jump,
    ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
        ] table [
            x=x,
            y=y,
            % use an expression to state that z values of 100 should be ignored
            z expr={\thisrow{z} == 100 ? NaN : \thisrow{z}},
        ] {
            x   y       z
            3.1 1.00    21.8
            3.1 0.98    19.16666667
            3.1 0.96    17.83333333
            3.1 0.94    16.16666667
            3.1 0.92    15.5
            3.1 0.90    14.83333333
            3.1 0.88    14.16666667
            3.1 0.86    13.5
            3.1 0.84    12.83333333
            3.1 0.82    12.16666667
            3.1 0.80    12.16666667
            3.1 0.78    11.5
            3.1 0.76    100
            3.1 0.74    100

            3.3 1       21.83333333
            3.3 0.98    20.5
            3.3 0.96    18.5
            3.3 0.94    16.83333333
            3.3 0.92    15.5
            3.3 0.9     14.83333333
            3.3 0.88    14.16666667
            3.3 0.86    13.5
            3.3 0.84    12.83333333
            3.3 0.82    12.16666667
            3.3 0.8     12.16666667
            3.3 0.78    11.5
            3.3 0.76    11.5
            3.3 0.74    11.5

            3.5 1       21.83333333
            3.5 0.98    20.5
            3.5 0.96    18.5
            3.5 0.94    17.16666667
            3.5 0.92    15.5
            3.5 0.9     14.83333333
            3.5 0.88    14.16666667
            3.5 0.86    13.5
            3.5 0.84    12.83333333
            3.5 0.82    12.16666667
            3.5 0.8     12.16666667
            3.5 0.78    11.5
            3.5 0.76    11.5
            3.5 0.74    11.5
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. However, I don't know why I can't place a colorbar using the option `colorbar`, do you have any idea why?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. Did you place `colorbar` in the `axis` options?

Comment: My bad, it works fine. I placed it in the wrong place. Have a nice day.

Comment: Another question please, if I don't have column headers, how can I rewrite this piece of syntax `z expr={\thisrow{z} == 100 ? NaN : \thisrow{z}}`?

Comment: Replace `\thisrow{<header name>}` by `\thisrowno{<col number>}`. Remember that `<col number>` starts with 0.

Comment: Your patience is highly appreciated. Regards!

Comment: I would be highly grateful if you don't mind considering my [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411110/2288) to this one.