# I need to plot two functions together over triangular domains using tikz. How do I do that?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, domain

So here it is the problem. I have two bivariate functions with different expressions whose graphs I would like to plot. The first part of the problem consists in defining their domain, because they are triangular instead of rectangular. The second part of the problem consists in plotting both graphs together, using the same figure.

To be more precise, the first domain corresponds to the triangle determined by (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1), while the second domain corresponds to the triangle determined by (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1).

I have tried to use the suggestions at [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213089/plotting-a-function-on-a-triangular-domain-using-pgfplots) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213389/clipping-3d-plots-using-pgfplots), but I have not succeeded so far.

Could someone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go for the the option in your second link. We can parametrize the triangles as follows:

1. Triangle (0,0), (0,1), (1,1): `x=u*v, y=v, 0<=u,v<=1`.
2. Triangle (0,0), (1,0), (1,1): `x=u, y=u*v, 0<=u,v<=1`.

If we want to plot, for example, the paraboloids `z=2-x^2+y^2=2-u^2*v^2-v^2` (first triangle) and `z=x^2+y^2=u^2+u^2*v^2` (second triangle) we can do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage   {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset  {compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  zmin=0,
  zmax=2,
  variable  =u,
  variable y=v,
  view={30}{45}
]
  % (0,0) (0,1) (1,1) parametrization x=u*v, y=v --->          x,  y, 2-  x^2  -y^2                  
  \addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1, colormap name=hot] (u*v, v, 2-u^2*v^2-v^2);  
  % (0,0) (1,0) (1,1) parametrization x=u, y=u*v --->                         x,  y,  x^2+  y^2
  \addplot3[surf,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1, colormap name=viridis,opacity=0.8] (u, u*v, u^2+u^2*v^2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A simple example using tikz is as follows.

Updated: mesh lines added

```
    % !Tex program = xelatex
% !Tex encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
   \usetikzlibrary{perspective}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
% define colors 
\colorlet{fillbottom}{yellow!60}
\colorlet{filltop}{blue!20}
\colorlet{curvecolor}{red}
\colorlet{meshcolor}{orange}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={60}{30},scale=2]
 
 %===================================
 %  surface 1: z=xy with domain boundary x=1, y=x, y=0
 % surface 2:  z=x^2+y^2 with domain boundary y=x, y=1, x=0
 %===================================
 \tikzset{%
              declare function={%%
              f(\u,\v)=\u*\v;
              g(\u,\v)=\u^2+\v^2;
              }%%
         }%

\def \xa {1} \def \xb {1} 

% set coordinates 
     \def \mxmin{0}\def \xdash{0} \def\mxmax{2.5}
     \def \mymin{0}\def \ydash{0} \def\mymax{2}
     \def \mzmin{0}\def \zdash{0} \def\mzmax{2}
    % x axis
      \draw [dashed] (\mxmin,0,0) -- (\xdash,0,0);
      \draw[->,>=latex] (\xdash,0,0)--(\mxmax,0,0) node[left] {$x$};  
     % y axis
     \draw[dashed] (0,\mymin,0)--(0,\ydash,0) ;
     \draw[->,>=latex] (0,\ydash,0)--(0,\mymax,0) node[right] {$y$};  
     % z axis 
       \draw[dashed] (0,0,\mzmin)--(0,0,\zdash); 
      \draw[->,>=latex] (0,0,\zdash)--(0,0,\mzmax) node[left] {$z$};  
 
 
 % domain of surface 1
 \draw (\xa,0,0) -- (\xa,\xb,0); 
 \draw[dashed] (0,0,0)--(\xa,\xb,0);
 \draw ({0.7*\xa},{0.3^\xb},0) node {$D_1$};
 \fill[color=fillbottom,opacity=0.2] 
  (0,0,0)--(\xa,0,0) --(\xa,\xb,0)--cycle;
  
% domain of surface 2
 \draw[dashed] (\xa,\xb,0) -- (0,\xb,0); 
  \draw ({0.3*\xa},{0.7^\xb},0) node {$D_2$};
 \fill[color=fillbottom,opacity=0.2] 
  (0,0,0)--(0,\xb,0) --(\xa,\xb,0)--cycle;
     
% special points
    \node at (\xa,\xb,0)[right] {$y=x$};
    \node at (\xa,0,0)[left] {$\xa$};
    \node at (0,\xb,0)[above right] {$\xb$};

% help lines
   \draw[thick,dashed] (\xa,\xb,0)--(\xa,\xb,{g(\xa,\xb)}); 
   \draw[thick,dashed] (0,\xb,0)--(0,\xb,{g(0,\xb)});

%  surface 1: z=xy
  \draw[thick,draw=curvecolor,fill=filltop,opacity=0.4] 
   (0,0,0)--
   plot[domain=0:\xa,samples=50,smooth] ({\x},{\x},{f(\x,\x)})
   --
   plot[variable=\y,domain=\xb:0,samples=50,smooth] (1,{\y},{f(1,\y)}) 
   --
   plot[domain=\xa:0,samples=50,smooth] (\x,{0},{f(\x,0)}) 
   --cycle;

% surface 1: mesh lines   
   \foreach \k in {0.1, 0.2,...,0.9}
   {
    \draw[meshcolor] plot[domain=0:\xa,samples=50,smooth] (\x,{\k*\x},{f(\x,{\k*\x})});
   }
%  surface 2: z=x^2+y^2
  \filldraw[thick,draw=curvecolor,fill=filltop,opacity=0.4] 
   (0,0,0)--
   plot[domain=0:\xa,samples=50,smooth] ({\x},{\x},{g(\x,\x)})
   --
   plot[domain=\xa:0,samples=50,smooth] ({\x},{1},{g(\x,1)}) 
   --
   plot[variable=\y,domain=\xb:0,samples=50,smooth] ({0},{\y},{g(0,\y)}) 
   --cycle;
% surface 2: mesh lines   
   \foreach \k in {0.1, 0.2,...,0.9}
   {
    \draw[meshcolor] plot[variable=\y,domain=0:\xb,samples=50,smooth] ({\k*\y},\y,{g(\k*\y,\y)});
   }
     
 %======================
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]